# How to temporarily disable foreign key constraint in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have to update a record which have foreign key constraint.
i have to assign 0 to the column which is defined as foreign key
while updating django don't let me to update record.

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do, there is a better way than *disabling a FK constraint*, which I don't think is possible

Comment: You can disable the constraint permanently with the [`db_constraint`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.db_constraint) option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ForeignKey** is a many-to-one relationship. Requires a positional argument: the class to which the model is related.

It must be **Relation** (class) or **Null** (if null allowed). You cannot set 0 (integer) to ForeignKey columnn.